# Composition in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, composition

I am learning the concepts of Composition in JS. Below is my demo code.

The `moveBy` function assigns the values correctly to `x` and `y`.

However, the `setFillColor` function does not assign the passed value to `fillColor`.

What exactly is happening when the `setFillColor` function is called?

```js
const withMoveBy = (shape) => ({
  moveBy: (diffX, diffY) => {
    shape.dimensions.x += diffX;
    shape.dimensions.y += diffY;
  },
});

const withSetFillColor = (shape) => ({
  setFillColor: (color) => {
    console.log(shape.fillColor);                      // 1
    shape.fillColor = color;
    shape.dimensions.fillColor = color;
    console.log(shape.fillColor);                      // 2
  },
});

const shapeRectangle = (dimensions) => ({
  type: 'rectangle',
  fillColor: 'white',
  dimensions,
});

const shapeCircle = (dimensions) => ({
  type: 'circle',
  fillColor: 'white',
  dimensions,
});

const createShape = (type, dimensions) => {
  let shape = null;
  switch (type) {
    case 'rectangle': {
      shape = shapeRectangle(dimensions);
      break;
    }
    case 'circle': {
      shape = shapeCircle(dimensions);
      break;
    }
  }

  if (shape) {
    shape = {
      ...shape,
      ...withSetFillColor(shape),
      ...withMoveBy(shape),
    };
  }
  return shape;
};

let r = createShape('rectangle', {
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
});

let c = createShape('circle', { x: 10, y: 10, diameter: 10 });

r.moveBy(2, 3);
c.moveBy(1, 2);

r.setFillColor('red');
c.setFillColor('blue');

console.log(r);
console.log(c);
```

OUTPUT:

Line marked as `// 1` prints `white` in case of rectangle as well as circle.

Line marked as `// 2` prints `red` for rectangle and `blue` for circle.

The final output is:

```
{
  "type": "rectangle",
  "fillColor": "white",
  "dimensions": {
    "x": 3,
    "y": 4,
    "width": 10,
    "height": 10,
    "fillColor": "red"
  }
}
{
  "type": "circle",
  "fillColor": "white",
  "dimensions": {
    "x": 11,
    "y": 12,
    "diameter": 10,
    "fillColor": "blue"
  }
}
```

The `fillColor` as the property of object is still `white`.
However, the one inside of `dimensions` has taken the correct value.

Comment: You create `shape`, pass it to `withSetFillColor()` but then *create a different `shape` object*. Let's call it `shape2` for simplicity. So, when you call `withSetFillColor('red')` on `shape2`, only `shape1` gets changed. Both objects share `dimensions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from this assignment in `createShape` - annotations by me:

```js
    // creating the "new object"
    shape = {
      ...shape, // shallow copying of the "old object"
      ...withSetFillColor(shape),
      ...withMoveBy(shape),
    };
```

Here, you create a **new object** that is composed of:

- shallow-copied properties of the existing `...shape` (type, fillcolor, **dimensions** which is an object)
- `setFillColor`, a closure that is bound to `shape` (the **old object**)
- `moveBy`, a closure that is bound to `shape` (the **old object**)

After this statement is executed, you have created two shapes:

- The "old object", which the methods operate on
- The "new object", which you return

Out of the properties copied from the old object, only **dimensions** is a non-primitive value, so it is shared between the instances.

Then, when you call:

```js
r.moveBy(2, 3);
```

it changes `oldShape.dimensions`, but it's the same object as `newShape.dimensions`, so it's visible in the output.

However, this call:

```js
r.setFillColor('red');
```

modifies the `fillColor` property of the `oldShape`, which you are not seeing. It also writes to `oldShape.dimensions.fillColor`, which, again, is shared between the objects, so that change is visible in both.

Comment: That was quite insightful. What should be the right way of creating the objects?

Comment: @thewebjackal Don't create a new object - assign properties to the existing object using e.g. `Object.assign`, so that there's only 1 reference to a `shape` that you have to deal with.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Also, in this example - https://youtu.be/wfMtDGfHWpA?t=291 - as the first argument for Object.assign is empty object, it never gets the name and speed properties. In my case, the first parameter should be shape. Or in the example, it should be state. I hope I am right.

Answer (score 1):

Let me illustrate the problem by re-writing your code. I have removed some of the details to focus on the issue only. Added annotations and logging to the code to show more clearly what happens:

```js
const withSetFillColor = (shape) => ({
  setFillColor: (color) => {
    console.log(`now changing shape with id [${shape.id}]`);
    shape.fillColor = color;
    shape.dimensions.fillColor = color;
  },
});

const shapeRectangle = (dimensions) => ({
  id: 1, //add an ID of the created object for illustrative purpose
  type: 'rectangle',
  fillColor: 'white',
  dimensions,
});

const createShape = (type, dimensions) => {
  //variable is now named 1 to showcase what happens
  let shape1 = null;
  switch (type) {
    case 'rectangle': {
      shape1 = shapeRectangle(dimensions);
      break;
    }
  }
  
  //this is effectively what happens when you clone and reassign an object:
  //a *second one* is created but the first one persists
  let shape2 = null;
  if (shape1) {
    shape2 = {
      ...shape1,
      ...withSetFillColor(shape1),
      id: 2, //make it a different ID for illustrative purpose
    };
  }
  
  console.log(`Created shape1 and shape2 and they are the same: ${shape1 === shape2}`);
  console.log(`The dimensions object is the same: ${shape1.dimensions === shape2.dimensions}`);
  
  return shape2;
};

let r = createShape('rectangle', {
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
});

r.setFillColor('red');

console.log(r);
```

You create and manipulate two different objects. This is the reason why the code assigns a property to the object but it appears as if it is not changed.

There are several way to deal with this.

#### Only create one object and assign to it

If you use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) you can directly change one object instead of having two competing ones. Thus, passing the object to the `withX()` functions will work as intended.

```js
const withMoveBy = (shape) => ({
  moveBy: (diffX, diffY) => {
    shape.dimensions.x += diffX;
    shape.dimensions.y += diffY;
  },
});

const withSetFillColor = (shape) => ({
  setFillColor: (color) => {
    shape.fillColor = color;
    shape.dimensions.fillColor = color;
  },
});

const shapeRectangle = (dimensions) => ({
  type: 'rectangle',
  fillColor: 'white',
  dimensions,
});

const shapeCircle = (dimensions) => ({
  type: 'circle',
  fillColor: 'white',
  dimensions,
});

const createShape = (type, dimensions) => {
  let shape = null;
  switch (type) {
    case 'rectangle': {
      shape = shapeRectangle(dimensions);
      break;
    }
    case 'circle': {
      shape = shapeCircle(dimensions);
      break;
    }
  }

  if (shape) {
    //use Object assign to only manipulate one `shape` object
    Object.assign( 
      shape, 
      withSetFillColor(shape), 
      withMoveBy(shape)
    );
  }
  return shape;
};

let r = createShape('rectangle', {
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
});

let c = createShape('circle', { x: 10, y: 10, diameter: 10 });

r.moveBy(2, 3);
c.moveBy(1, 2);

r.setFillColor('red');
c.setFillColor('blue');

console.log(r);
console.log(c);
```

#### Don't use arrow functions, use `this` instead

Alternatively, use regular functions or [the shorthand method definition syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) which lets you use `this`. You can then add these methods to your object and use `this` to refer to the object, instead of having to pass it in.

```js
const withMoveBy = { //no need for a function to produce the object
  moveBy(diffX, diffY) { //shorthand method syntax
    this.dimensions.x += diffX;
    this.dimensions.y += diffY;
  },
};

const withSetFillColor = { //no need for a function to produce the object
  setFillColor(color) { //shorthand method syntax
    this.fillColor = color;
    this.dimensions.fillColor = color;
  },
};

const shapeRectangle = (dimensions) => ({
  type: 'rectangle',
  fillColor: 'white',
  dimensions,
});

const shapeCircle = (dimensions) => ({
  type: 'circle',
  fillColor: 'white',
  dimensions,
});

const createShape = (type, dimensions) => {
  let shape = null;
  switch (type) {
    case 'rectangle': {
      shape = shapeRectangle(dimensions);
      break;
    }
    case 'circle': {
      shape = shapeCircle(dimensions);
      break;
    }
  }

  if (shape) {
    shape = {
      ...shape,
      ...withSetFillColor,
      ...withMoveBy,
    };
  }
  return shape;
};

let r = createShape('rectangle', {
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
});

let c = createShape('circle', { x: 10, y: 10, diameter: 10 });

r.moveBy(2, 3);
c.moveBy(1, 2);

r.setFillColor('red');
c.setFillColor('blue');

console.log(r);
console.log(c);
```

#### A *mixed* approach

This is more of an explanation of what's happening than an actual new approach.

Both of the above both work but show two sides of the same coin. Combining objects together is called [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)*. Mixins are *similar* to object composition because you build up more complex objects from simpler ones but also a separate category of its own since you do it via concatenation.

Traditionally, you would use `Object.assign(obj, mixinA, mixinB)` for adding things to `obj`. Which makes it similar to the first approach. However, `mixinA` and `mixinB` would be actual objects like in the second approach.

Using class syntax, there is an interesting alternative to add mixins to a class. I'm adding it here just to show it - it's totally OK to not use classes and use regular objects instead.

```js
const withMoveBy = Base => class extends Base { //mixin
  moveBy(diffX, diffY) { 
    this.dimensions.x += diffX;
    this.dimensions.y += diffY;
  }
};

const withSetFillColor = Base => class extends Base { //mixin
  setFillColor(color) {
    this.fillColor = color;
    this.dimensions.fillColor = color;
  }
};

class Shape {
  constructor({type, fillColor, dimensions}) {
    this.type = type;
    this.fillColor = fillColor;
    this.dimensions = dimensions;
  }
}

const shapeRectangle = (dimensions) => ({
  type: 'rectangle',
  fillColor: 'white',
  dimensions,
});

const shapeCircle = (dimensions) => ({
  type: 'circle',
  fillColor: 'white',
  dimensions,
});

const createShape = (type, dimensions) => {
  let shapeArgs = null;
  switch (type) {
    case 'rectangle': {
      shapeArgs = shapeRectangle(dimensions);
      break;
    }
    case 'circle': {
      shapeArgs = shapeCircle(dimensions);
      break;
    }
  }

  let shape = null;
  if (shapeArgs) {
    //add mixins to the Shape class
    const mixedInConstructor = withMoveBy(withSetFillColor(Shape));
    //create the enhanced class
    shape = new mixedInConstructor(shapeArgs);
  }
  return shape;
};

let r = createShape('rectangle', {
  x: 1,
  y: 1,
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
});

let c = createShape('circle', { x: 10, y: 10, diameter: 10 });

r.moveBy(2, 3);
c.moveBy(1, 2);

r.setFillColor('red');
c.setFillColor('blue');

console.log(r);
console.log(c);
```

* Yes, the title was a pun. You can laugh now.